# Eclipse is closing while Creating new java project

Tags: eclipse

I am getting following log generated when trying to create a new java project in the eclipse editor

Please see the logs below

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000b08, pid=3452, tid=1508
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000b08
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x01bfac00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1508, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000b08

    Registers:
    EAX=0x71608e7f, EBX=0x299f9eb8, ECX=0x01bfad28, EDX=0x00000000
    ESP=0x0012ed78, EBP=0x0012edac, ESI=0x299f9eb8, EDI=0x01bfac00
    EIP=0x00000b08, EFLAGS=0x00010202

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x0012ed78)
    0x0012ed78:   00000b08 00000000 00000000 0012ee00
    0x0012ed88:   0012edec 0012ed8c 299f9eb8 0012edc0
    0x0012ed98:   299fa570 00000000 299f9eb8 00000000
    0x0012eda8:   0012edbc 0012ede4 021532c7 0fa797d8
    0x0012edb8:   02158989 00000b08 00000000 0012edc4
    0x0012edc8:   299f9e34 0012edec 299fa570 00000000
    0x0012edd8:   299f9e38 0012edbc 0012edec 0012ee10
    0x0012ede8:   021532c7 0fa798b8 0012edf0 299ed9fa 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000b08)
0x00000ae8:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]
```

Comment: Which OS? Which Eclipse? Which JVM?

Comment: OS Windows XP  Eclipse Juno : version 4.2

Comment: RE version: 7.0_25-b17
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000b08

Comment: If this repeats with newest Java 7, run a thorough memory check.